# why does spring-data-mongodb 1.10 not support readConcern option?

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

My Application encountered a problem: a thread update a mongodb doc, but another thread can't get the latest update immediately;

Then I found [this document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#real-time-order) about consistency.

It needs set the read concern "linearizable", and the MongoClientOptions class does have the "readConcern" but the spring-data-mongodb label `<mongo:client-options...>` doesn't have the corresponding option.

My MongoDB version is 3.4 and spring-data-mongodb version is 1.10.11

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps you in your particular case, but you can set the concern for the entire MongoClient

```
@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3/?readConcernLevel=linearizable&writeConcernLevel=majority"));
}
```